# Need to track PC down times using PHP ping and display time down D:HH:MM

Tags: php, ping

I currently have this code, which runs as a ph that works to let me know if the pc's are pinging:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
<body>

<h1>PC Test Ping Status</h1>

<?php
$host="10.161.10.98";
exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)
echo "<p>p2 On-Line</p>";
else
echo "<p>p2 Off-Line !</p>";

$host="10.161.10.125";
exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)
echo "<p>p3 On-Line</p>";
else
echo "<p>p3 Off-Line!</p>";

?> 


</body>
</html>
```

I want to track the time since the last successful ping if the pc isn't pinging.

Comment: Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class, and store the value in a session or database.

Comment: Can this be stored in a file like a txt?

Comment: yes. a text file can be considered just another form of database.

Comment: i'm sorry, would an example be possible?

Comment: sure, I will throw an example together. give me a little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a text file, as requested. A few notes:

1. For simplicity, I suggest using CURL instead of `exec` as it should be a lot faster and more reliable. This checks for the HTTP status code "200" which means it returned a valid request.
2. You will need to make sure your text file/s have the appropriate read & write permissions.
3. I've updated this answer to also address [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682718/pull-ip-addresses-and-pc-names-from-a-txt-file).

---

The initial text file in this example is named `data.txt` and contains the following:

```
p1|google.com|
p2|yahoo.com|
p2|amazon.com|
```

The following code will cycle through each server in the list, and update the records with the latest date if it's online.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
<body>

<h1>PC Test Ping Status</h1>

<?php

function ping($addr) {
    $ch = curl_init($addr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //get response code
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($code === 200) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$file = 'data.txt';
$servers = array_filter(explode("\n", file_get_contents($file)));
foreach ($servers as $key => $server) {
    list($sname, $saddr, $suptime) = explode('|', $server);
    if (ping($saddr)) {
        echo "<p>$sname is online</p>";
        $date = new DateTime();
        $suptime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
        echo "<p>$sname is offline since: ";
        if (trim($suptime) !== '') {
            echo $suptime . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo 'unknown</p>';
        }
    }
    $servers[$key] = implode('|', array($sname, $saddr, $suptime)) . "\n";
}
file_put_contents($file, $servers);

?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I seem to be doing something wrong, it returns "server1 is offline since: unknown" all the time. Right now the txt file is empty, which I think it should be if the server is up, correct?

Comment: that is correct. verify you're actually receiving a "200" status code, and if so, try enabling error reporting or checking your logs.

Comment: I'm confused by the 200 status code, originally I was checking for a ping with exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)

is this a better method?

Comment: I guess I'm also confused how the ping gets executed and checked now

Comment: @user50338 I've modified my answer, hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: I think I'm close with the date logging, I think part of the problem is my third collumn formatting... How should the txt doc look for this?

Comment: Don't put anything in the third column, just like my example. It will be populated by PHP.