# Pull IP addresses and PC names from a txt file

Tags: php

I currently have this code, which runs as a PHP script that lets me know if the PCs are pinging:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
<body>

<h1>PC Test Ping Status</h1>

<?php
$host="10.191.10.98";
exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)
echo "<p>p2 On-Line</p>";
else
echo "<p>p2 Off-Line !</p>";

$host="10.191.10.125";
exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
if ($result == 0)
echo "<p>p3 On-Line</p>";
else
echo "<p>p3 Off-Line!</p>";

?> 


</body>
</html>
```

I want to pull the PC name and address data from columns in a txt file instead like:

```
pc1 10.191.10.1
pc2 10.191.10.2
pc3 10.191.10.3
pc4 10.191.10.4
```

and so on... so we can add to the list and it will keep going.

Comment: `file_put_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I think it would be better with a json file rather than a flat text file.

`data =  { 'pc1':'10.191.10.1','pc2':'10.191.10.1'....}` then you could use it like so : `var pcs = JSON.parse('../../data/file.json'); alert(pcs.data.pc1);` Did not test it.

Comment: linking [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681077/need-to-track-pc-down-times-using-php-ping-and-display-time-down-dhhmm/41682607) here for reference, since it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');    //Replace with full path to the file.
$lines = explode("\n", $file);     //Might have to use \r\n depending on your system.
foreach($lines as $pingTarget) {
    $pcs = explode(' ',$pingTarget);
    $host=$pcs[1];
    exec("ping -c 2 " . $host, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0)
        echo "<p>".$pcs[0]." On-Line</p>";
    else
        echo "<p>".$pcs[0]." Off-Line !</p>";
}
?>
```

This way you will extract the contents of the text file and then loop through each line, giving output for each system.

Depending on your timeouts you might want to set a time limit inside the loop to give each system to respond, especially if you have a long list of PCs to ping:

```
set_time_limit(5);   //Set time in seconds
```

Comment: I wonder if I need to label the top of the document for it to recognize the collumns?

Comment: Sweet, got it to behave after I tidied up the txt file! This is crazy to ask, but leys say I wanted to go a step further and show off-line in red txt, and on-line in green

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegEx query to extract the IP's and then add them to an array. Also, instead of you manually adding the hostnames, let PHP resolve the hostnames for you by using `gethostbyaddr($v)`. In my example, I've used Google DNS to show DNS resolve and your private IP's which I cant resolve as they are not on my LAN. It's handy because if you ever rename a PC or your IP's are using DHCP (Grabs a new IP address every X days), you do not need to update your text file.

```
$ipLst = file_get_contents('ip.txt'); 
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $ipLst, $ipArr); //Match an IP and add to ipArr Array

foreach($ipArr[0] as $k=>$v) { //Loop through ipArr

    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($v); //Reverse lookup to resolve hostname

    exec("ping -c 2 " . $v, $output, $result);

    if ($result === 0) {
        echo "<p>$hostname is On-Line!</p>"; //Echo Hostname or IP if its unable to resolve

    }else{
        echo "<p>$hostname is Off-Line!</p>"; //Echo Hostname or IP if its unable to resolve
    }

}
```

**Text File:**

```
pc1 8.8.8.8
pc2 10.191.10.2
pc3 10.191.10.3
pc4 10.191.10.4
```

**Output:**

```
google-public-dns-a.google.com is On-Line!

10.191.10.2 is Off-Line!

10.191.10.3 is Off-Line!

10.191.10.4 is Off-Line!
```